# QT Signals & slots in diffrent class

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slot

My program has 2 classes. One of them is MainWindow and another is Calc.
In main window I use automatic generated function on_PushButton_clicked. This function should send two values: double & char to function in Calc.

first:

```
void MainWindow::on_OneButton_clicked(){
QObject::connect(ui->ZeroButton , SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(...)) );
ui->TextEdit->insertPlainText("1");
}
```

second :

```
void Calc::Add(double val, char oper){
//compute something 
}
```

It's my first app with Qt and I do not know how can I connect them. I've searched similar question on this forum, but can't found.
Sorry if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to well understand what signal/slot mecanism is, and what you are doing.

Signal/slot mecanism is a Qt concept to link a function (signal) to another function (slot). To "make a link" between a signal and a slot, you have to connect them using QObject::connect(...).

When you use automatic generated function on_PushButton_Clicked() with Qt designer, you, in fact, "make a link" between the signal clicked() emitted when the pushButton is clicked, with a slot on_PushButton_Clicked(). However, the connection between this signal and this slot doesn't appear in your code so it may be confusing and that's why I'm pointing it out.

When you write this:

```
void MainWindow::on_OneButton_clicked(){
    QObject::connect(ui->ZeroButton , SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(...)) );
    ui->TextEdit->insertPlainText("1");
}
```

You create a connection with zeroButton when clicked and a slot, each time you clic on your button. As a connection is valid till an object is destructed, if you clic again on your pushButton, you'll have a second connection between zeroButton when clicked and your slot.

A better way to create connection is to use connect(...) function when you create your object (mainWindow in your case).

To make it simple for your calculator, you can create 9 buttons for digits, 4 buttons for operators, and 1 button to compute everything.

In your mainwindow constructor, you could have something like:

```
connect(ui->pushButton1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onPushButton1Clicked()));
.... // Every other signal for each button
connect(ui->pushButtonEqual, SIGNAL(clicked(), this, SLOT(onPushButtonEqualClicked());
```

And in your body

```
void MainWindow::onPushButton1Clicked()
{
    // concatenate current value + 1
    ui->textEdit->insertPlainText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + "1");
}

void MainWindow::onPushButtonEqualClicked()
{
    // check textedit content (need a digit + operator + digit)
    ...
    // compute result
    ...
    // write result in TextEdit
    ...
}
```

I hope it will help a little bit ;)